# C# calling function in C++ .dll fails to open com port

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port, interop

While using the exact same arguments as in the C++ example that uses the same .dll, the function `Open()` successfully opens the COM port. While calling the same function using the same arguments in C#, `Open()` fails to open the COM port, returning `-1`. I do not know why `Open()` successfully opens the COM port when calling from C++, but is unsuccessful when calling from C#.

The header file looks like:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int Open(char* serialNo, int nBaud, int timeout);
```

The C# import looks like

```
[DllImport(dllLocation)]
private static extern int Open(byte[] serialNo, int nBuad, int timeout);
```

and I am calling `Open()` using

```
char[] inp = new char[4];
inp[0] = 'C';
inp[1] = 'O';
inp[2] = 'M';
inp[3] = '6';
res = Open(inp, 115200, 10);
```

The C++ example looks like

```
char com[20] = { 0 };
cin >> com;
int hdl = Open(com, 115200, 10);
```

UPDATE

I have also tried using a string:

```
[DllImport(dllLocation)]
private static extern int Open([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string serialNo, int nBuad, int timeout);
```

```
string inp = "COM6";
int res = Open(inp, 115200, 10);
```

I have tried proceeding 0s:

```
char[] inp = new char[5];
inp[0] = 'C';
inp[1] = 'O';
inp[2] = 'M';
inp[3] = '6';
inp[4] = '\0';
```

I have tried:

```
DllImport(dllLocation)]
private static extern int Open(byte[] serialNo, int nBuad, int timeout);
```

```
byte[] inp = new byte[4];
inp[0] = 67;
inp[1] = 79;
inp[2] = 77;
inp[3] = 54;
int res = Open(inp, 115200, 10);
```

Comment: Change `char[] inp = new char[4];` to `char[] inp = new char[5];` and then set `inp[4] = 0;` As you need to null terminate your string.

Comment: hehe ... use `string` with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`  instead `byte[]` ... so you can simply call `Open("COM6", ...)` (or you can set charset to ansi encoding and don't use MarshalAs)

Comment: @user20716902 I have tried setting inp[4] = '\0'; - didn't work. I have also tried changing the C++ char size to be 4, i.e, `char com[4] = { 0 };` - this did not fail.

Comment: also there is already `System.IO.Ports` ...

Comment: your change to the c++ only works due to the joys of undefined behaviour

Comment: `char` is not `byte` in C# it is twice of the size (`char` on C/C++ side can be `byte` on C# side but not `char`)

Comment: if `char* serialNo` is out , then `Open` on C++ side is badly designe...as you dont know size of `serialNo` buffer so you cannot fill it safely

Comment: @Selvin, I have just tried your string suggestion, this did not work either.

I am familiar with System.IO.Ports - but this .dll is required because I do not know what is sent to the serial port to just implement it directly.

I have also tried sending as a byte[] which has not worked.

I shall edit my question to include what I have just tried.

Comment: this doesn't make sens ... it should work with `string` ... check if plain C++ works ... maybe given port just doesn't exist (fx check `const char com[] = "COM6";` on C++ side)

Comment: Always it can be a problem with calling convention ... in c/c++ for exported it is `cdecl` and in C# on windows is `stdcall` ... so maybe `[DllImport(dllLocation, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` and just `string` without `MarshalAs` could work